# On respecting constness while avoiding reallocating on the heap

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

I extended a const function, and everytime that const function is called I have to create a map.  As in

```
int foo() const {
  map<int, int> bar;
  // setup bar
  ...

  return utility::eval(bar);
}
```

But declaring bar is very expensive.  I can cut my CPU footprint in half by declaring bar is an instance variable, but doing so doesn't respect constess.  Is there a non-hacky way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: The best thing is probably to fix that `eval` function to have a more sensible interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
class Foo {
    mutable map<int, int> bar;
    ...
}
```

See also http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html and triple check whether it makes sense for you to actually use `mutable` here.

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as a `mutable` member variable.

But you shouldn't use `mutable` as a hacky work-around for situations where you've engineered yourself into a const corner.  You should only use it in situations where modifying the variable doesn't change the logical state of the class (i.e. it has no observable impact on the results that member functions produce).  Yours sounds like such a situation, so it should be fine.